# Function returning not defined when called from script file

Tags: javascript, html

After learning how to put all javascript code into a single page by declaring and calling functions like so:

```
function script() {
  const foo=document.querySelector('.foo');

  if(!foo) {
    return
  }

  code here....
}

script();
```

I am now getting an error:

`ReferenceError: timer is not defined`

The code works without any problem when run independent, but when nested within a function the timer is no longer defined. Here is the working code:

```js
let upgradeTime = 535680;
let seconds = upgradeTime;

function timer() {
  let days = Math.floor(seconds / 24 / 60 / 60);
  let hoursLeft = Math.floor(seconds - days * 86400);
  let hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
  let minutesLeft = Math.floor(hoursLeft - hours * 3600);
  let minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
  let remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

  function pad(n) {
    return n < 10 ? "0" + n : n;
  }
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = `${pad(days)}: ${pad(hours)}: ${pad(minutes)}: ${pad(remainingSeconds)}`;
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Completed";
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
}
let countdownTimer = setInterval("timer()", 1000);
```

```html
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
```

Now, if I place all the above code within the following function `timerScript()`, followed by a call to the function, the ReferenceError appears. I'm not even running the `if(!foo) { return }` but am still getting an error.

What am I missing here?

[Here is the CodePen that does not work](https://codepen.io/jeremylucas/pen/NWPMjKw)

```
function timerScript() {

  code here....

}

timerScript();
```

```js
function timerScript() {
  let upgradeTime = 535680;
  let seconds = upgradeTime;

  function timer() {
    let days = Math.floor(seconds / 24 / 60 / 60);
    let hoursLeft = Math.floor(seconds - days * 86400);
    let hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
    let minutesLeft = Math.floor(hoursLeft - hours * 3600);
    let minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
    let remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

    function pad(n) {
      return n < 10 ? "0" + n : n;
    }
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = `${pad(days)}: ${pad(hours)}: ${pad(minutes)}: ${pad(remainingSeconds)}`;
    if (seconds == 0) {
      clearInterval(countdownTimer);
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Completed";
    } else {
      seconds--;
    }
  }
  let countdownTimer = setInterval("timer()", 1000);
}
timerScript();
```

```html
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(timer, 1000)` is the right code. See [this working Pen](https://codepen.io/smar1216/pen/OJPZmPg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass a *function* to `setInterval` (and `setTimeout`). When you pass a string to them, the browser tries to access that string as a variable on the top level, so

```
let countdownTimer = setInterval("timer()", 1000);
```

will result in `window.timer` being called. If `window.timer` doesn't exist, an error will be thrown.

Pass the actual function instead of a string:

```
let countdownTimer = setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

This way, the `timer` variable in the outer *but not global* scope can be seen from the `setInterval` call:

```js
(() => {
  const fn = () => null;
  
  // Works:
  setInterval(fn);
  
  // Won't work:
  // setInterval('fn()');
})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping and for the explanation of why it wasn't working before. This fixed the problem. I'll accept answer when able. Thanks again!